# Can i use windows store app C# code (namespace) for desktop app?

Tags: c#

Windows store apps (windows 8.1) provides c# sample code (namespaces) like for usb device communication. Can i use same c# sample code for windows desktop app or is there any way to use those in windows desktop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible!

If it is a good idea or not is another question. Scott Hanselman, well known Microsoft employee, has a nice blog about this problem. You can find it here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx